# ASP.NET Core 6.0 - Minimal APIs: What parameters are available to Map methods for handling routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I'm new to Minimal API which is available in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and based on Microsoft's tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0), one can define a sample route for Get method like this:

```
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
```

For the Post method, the following code [is provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-api-code):

```
...
app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (Todo todo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    db.Todos.Add(todo);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.Created($"/todoitems/{todo.Id}", todo);
});
...
```

In other part of the overview, some [Special types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#special-types) such as: `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest`, `HttpResponse`, ... are introduced and it seems that they are injected as parameters to routing methods (Get, Post, ...); So all these parameters are available:

```
app.MapPost("/test", (HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) => "Hello world!");
```

My questions is: What other parameters are available here:

```
app.MapPost("/test", (**HERE???**) => "Hello World!") {};
```

Comment: can't figure out, why all these `Map*` methods don't resolve in my Asp.Net Core 6 app? there is only a broad `Map` method

Comment: Thank you for asking this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#parameter-binding) has next supported binding sources:

- Route values
- Query string
- Header
- Body (as JSON)
- Services provided by dependency injection
- Custom

And next [special types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#special-types) (as you mentioned):

- `HttpContext` : The context which holds all the information about the current HTTP request or response.
- `HttpRequest` : The HTTP request
- `HttpResponse` : The HTTP response
- `System.Threading.CancellationToken` : The cancellation token associated with the current http request.
- `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` :  The user associated with the request (`HttpContext.User`).

Also you can use here types implementing [custom binding methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-binding):

- `TryParse` (to bind custom types for route, query, and header binding sources)

```
public static bool TryParse(string value, T out result);
public static bool TryParse(string value, IFormatProvider provider, T out result);
```

- `BindAsync`

```
public static ValueTask<T?> BindAsync(HttpContext context, ParameterInfo parameter);
public static ValueTask<T?> BindAsync(HttpContext context);
```

So basically you can have any parameter which can be resolved via DI (like `TodoDb db` from the example) or is a special type (`HttpContext` ...) or can be bound in some way (from the request data (like `Todo todo` from example will be bound from json request body) or by some custom magic).

Comment: how-to get IP Address client, and UserAgent **without System.Web.Http** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet:  
`app.MapGet("/callingip", (HttpRequest request) =>  
{  
      return request.HttpContext.Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString() + 
    System.Environment.NewLine + 
    request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();  });`

Answer (score 1):

> Route handlers are methods that execute when the route matches. Route
> handlers can be a function or any shape, including synchronous or
> asynchronous. Route handlers can be a lambda expression, a local
> function, an instance method or a static method.

This is from the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-handling.

There is an example here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-handling

also here is an example of a repository in the lambda
https://dev.to/moe23/getting-started-with-minimal-apis-in-net-6-4mi4

and another one using Func
https://medium.com/executeautomation/understanding-and-working-with-asp-net-core-6-0-minimal-api-1d25fd9ecc95